# How to make inline number bigger?

Tags: math-mode

How to make inline number enclosed in $...$ as big as those in $$...$$?

I just found that (b) looks ugly.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please help us to help you and add a *full* minimal working example [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Is easier for us in this way can help you copiyng and running code instead watch a screenshot.

Comment: I don't know how are you working, but if you add the `amsmath`package to your preamble, you could use `\dfrac` instead of `\frac` if `(b)` is a display equation.

Answer (score 3):

Please do not use `$$\dots $$` but `\[\dots \]` unless you are using plain TeX.

For your question. Just use `\dfrac{}{}` (display style fraction) from `amsmath`.

```
% arara: pdflatex    

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % loads amsmath

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \setcounter{enumi}{10}
    \item \begin{enumerate}
        \item $8!$
        \item $\dfrac{10!}{3!2!2!}$
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]